# How can I force SQL Server to recognise a new domain machine account?

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, windows-authentication

I'm setting up a new web server. The way our website's configured, the IIS application pools run as `NetworkService` on their host machines, and then each of the web server's domain computer accounts is added to the MYDOMAIN\Webservers security group, which is in turn granted SQL Server login access to various databases. The new web server's been added to the MYDOMAIN\Webservers group, but 30 minutes later, I'm still getting

> Login failed for user 'MYDOMAIN\SERVER03$'

I believe in the past, we just ignored it overnight and it was magically working in the morning... but I'd kinda like to know what I can do to force the new account and group membership to propagate across the domain so the SQL Server login system will recognise the new machine account. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the *full* message please?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to force replication of the Domain Controllers;

```
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816926(WS.10).aspx
```

It would work given time, as you noticed, by leaving it and letting the replication happen normally.

**Update**. The posted link is for Windows Server 2008/R2 which I use, but I believe it is the same for other versions.

Comment: No effect... tried propagating between domain controllers, verified that all three DCs now have the new server's computer account as a member of their local copy of the Webservers group; still get the same login error from SQL Server. :(